# shlex.split() returning whole command as a single string

Tags: python, string, python-3.6, shlex

shlex.split() is not giving the proper output on the input string.

In python interpreter, storing the input value in a variable produces the expected output.

But if i execute via a script, `shlex.split()` output is incorrect and input string did not split on whitespace.

```
>>> import shlex

>>> var = "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook --timeout=60 --module-path /var/sandeep> /playbooks/ --extra-vars '{ \"text\": \"DUMMY\", \"addition\": [\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", ], \"deletion\": [], \"update\": \"update\", \"path\": \"/var/sandeep\", }' /tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml"
>>>
>>>
>>> shlex.split(var)

['/usr/bin/ansible-playbook', '--timeout=60', '--module-path', '/var/sandeep/playbooks/', '--extra-vars', '{ "text": "DUMMY", "addition": ["1", "2", "3", ], "deletion": [], "update": "update", "path": "/var/sandeep", }', '/tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml']
```

```
def create_extra(text, extra_dict):
    extra = "'{{ \\\"text\\\": \\\"{}\\\", ".format(text)
    for key, value in extra_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            extra += '\\\"{}\\\": ['.format(key)
            for item in value:
                extra += '\\\"{}\\\", '.format(item)
            extra += '], '
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            extra += '\\\"{}\\\": {{'.format(key)
            for item_key, item_value in value.items():
                extra += '\\\"{}\\\": \\\"{}\\\", '.format(item_key, item_value)
            extra += "}, "
        else:
            extra += '\\\"{}\\\": \\\"{}\\\", '.format(key, value)
    extra += "}'"
    #print("extra: %s" % extra)
    return extra

extra_dict = {'addition': ["1", "2", "3"],
                   'deletion': [],
                   'update': 'update',
                   'path' : '/var/sandeep'
                  }


temp = create_extra("DUMMY", extra_dict)

"""create_extra function formats and return string"""

cmd = ('"/usr/bin/ansible-playbook ' +
        '--timeout=60 '  +
        '--module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ ' +
        '--extra-vars {} {}/{}"'.format(temp, "/tmp/sandeep", "/tmp/example.yaml"))

print(cmd)
print(shlex.split(cmd))
```

```
output of print(cmd)
"/usr/bin/ansible-playbook --timeout=60 --module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ --extra-vars '{ \"text\": \"DUMMY\", \"addition\": [\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", ], \"deletion\": [], \"update\": \"update\", \"path\": \"/var/sandeep\", }' /tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml"


Expected results:
['/usr/bin/ansible-playbook', '--timeout=60', '--module-path', '/var/sandeep/playbooks/', '--extra-vars', '{ "text": "DUMMY", "addition": ["1", "2", "3", ], "deletion": [], "update": "update", "path": "/var/sandeep", }', '/tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml']


Actual Results:
['/usr/bin/ansible-playbook --timeout=60 --module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ --extra-vars \'{ "text": "DUMMY", "addition": ["1", "2", "3", ], "deletion": [], "update": "update", "path": "/var/sandeep", }\' /tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml']
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Why would you use `shlex.split()` when you could build an explicit array? Assuming you're building a list to pass to `subprocess.Popen()` or the like, it's much safer to do something like `['--extra-vars', temp, os.path.join('/tmp/sandeep', 'example.yaml')]`; that way your code doesn't break if any of your names have spaces or literal quote characters.

Comment: Serge, it's completely reproducible if you use the OP's unmodified code. See https://ideone.com/TN6mfy

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I started by the first part which does not produce what question shows. I now realize that this was not the question. Will delete the comments...

Comment: @sandeepnagendra, ...it's important to keep in mind the difference between literal quotes and syntactic ones. Your original code in the interactive interpreter has only syntactic quotes and no literal ones; your code in the script that doesn't work has single-quotes as the syntactic ones, *and then literal quotes inside of them*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have added the output of cmd.  value of --extra-vars argument needs to be treated as a single string.  In my script, i have added shlex explicitly to test the functionality. But actually shlex is used in a separate library which feeds the input to subprocess.Popen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Input to --extra-vars is a dictionary which is quoted in single quotes. Please check the assignment in "var" variable

Comment: @sandeepnagendra, once again, the 100%-sure way to make sure something is a single string is to make it an explicit list entry. `[..., str(temp), ...]` is guaranteed to work correctly; anything you do with injecting literal quotes is *not*, unless you control the variable's content.

Comment: @sandeepnagendra, as for the assignment in your code, it relies on a nonstandard `create_extra` function you aren't providing (or showing an explicit `import` for), and this which I/we can't test. Mind the [mcve] definition.

Comment: `create_extra` is... yeegh. That frankly looks like it can and should just be replaced with `json.dumps(extra_dict)`, as soon as you get the need to shell-quote content out of the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `shlex` output is completely correct, because of the literal `"` characters contained in your string.

```
cmd = ('"/usr/bin/ansible-playbook ' +
#       ^- that right there
        '--timeout=60 '  +
        '--module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ ' +
        '--extra-vars {} {}/{}"'.format(temp, "/tmp/sandeep", "/tmp/example.yaml"))
#        and this right here -^
```

As your `print(cmd)` thus shows:

```
"/usr/bin/ansible-playbook --timeout=60 --module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ --extra-vars whatever /tmp/sandeep//tmp/example.yaml"
```

...your string starts with a `"` and ends with a `"`, and that makes it a single, literal string when parsed by a shell.

---

Just take those characters out, and the issue no longer happens:

```
cmd = ('/usr/bin/ansible-playbook ' +
       '--timeout=60 '  +
       '--module-path /var/sandeep/playbooks/ ' +
       '--extra-vars {} {}/{}'.format(temp, "/tmp/sandeep", "/tmp/example.yaml"))

print(cmd)
print(shlex.split(cmd))
```

---

However, you have **other** serious bugs, because string concatenation is inherently unsuited to building command lines. Instead of trying to take that approach at all, just build an array directly:

```
cmd = ['/usr/bin/ansible-playbook',
       '--timeout=60',
       '--module-path', '/var/sandeep/playbooks/',
       '--extra-vars', temp, os.path.join('/tmp/sandeep', '/tmp/example.yml')]
```

...and then values of `temp` or other variables with spaces or literal quotes will no longer break your code or allow arbitrary arguments to be injected.